# RegeX code for PowerShell Lookbehind not working matching on IP Addressing

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to parse a number of log files for IP addresses using PowerShell, but within those files I also have a number of false positives which are actually version numbers. There may be more but as a first start I wanted to grab all IPs that are not preceded by `Version=`.

I've tried a number of different variations of my Regex with no real success and hacking around in regex101.com has also given me no fruits.

```
(?<!Version=)(?<Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))
```

Ideally it should be something like:

- Not Match Version=10.0.0.1
- Match 10.0.0.1
- Match IPAddress=10.0.0.1
- Match IP=10.0.0.1

etc.

Comment: Please edit the question and add a few samples of data that should be matched and that shouldn't. Whilst at it, remove any `powershell-version` tags, as those should be used when the issue is about a specific version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add word boundaries (`\b`):

```
(?<!Version=)\b(?<Address> ... )\b
```

This prevents the match from starting *within* the IP address, which would otherwise happen. Without word boundaries, the area in square brackets would be a match:  `Version=1[0.0.0.1]`